# How does one kill a twisted child-process if no output is received within certain time-frame?

Tags: timeout, subprocess, twisted, spawn

How do I go about setting a time-out on "spawnProcess"? It needs to KILL the child-process if it does not receive any data within a certain time-frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about time-based events: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/time.html